# How to make a host migration to photon bolt?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, server, photon, bolt

Please tell me how to properly host a migration with a photon bolt. If possible, give documentation or step-by-step instructions

Comment: a good start would be GOOGLE and the dev Page. after 10 sec i found this:

https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/bolt/current/samples-and-tutorials/bolt-basics/bolt-102-getting-started

Answer (score 1):

Currently, [Photon Bolt](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/photon-bolt-free-127156) doesn't have any direct support for Host Migration. As this could be very specific to your game type.

On the other can, you check the `Bolt Samples Package` that contains an example of how Host Migration can be done, so you can use this as a starting point for your implementation.

Link: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/photon-bolt-sample-pack-85866